# getting corrupt file error while connecting c++ with mysql

Tags: c++, dll, linker, mysql-connector

I'm trying to connect MySql with C++ using visual studio 2019 but i'm getting a corrupt file error ,I downloaded the no-install-1.1.12-winx64 version of the connector(my pc is 64bit), then i downloaded boost 1.75.0 and linked it. i did my linkings as follows: (on All configurations, Win32/x64 platforms):
Configuration properties:
General:
(its a dll library so) conf. Type: .dll
VC++ Directories:
include directories - $(SolutionDir)mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.12-winx64\include
Library directories:
$(SolutionDir)mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.12-winx64\lib;

C/C++:
General:
Additional include Directories - $(solutiondir)boost_1_75_0

Linker:
General:
Additional Library Directories - $(SolutionDir)mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.12-
winx64\lib;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib
input:
mysqlcppconn.dll;libmysql.dll;%(AdditionalDependencies)

Im not a veteran when it comes to C++ linking so im pretty sure i did something wrong on the linking, please help! (Visual Studio 2019, Windows 10 64bit,10.0, Build 19041, 19041.vb_release.191206-1406)
here is the code i get this error on:

```
int main(){
cout << endl;
            cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!'" << endl;

            try {
                sql::Driver* driver;
                sql::Connection* con;
                sql::Statement* stmt;
                sql::ResultSet* res;

                driver = get_driver_instance();
                con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
                con->setSchema("test");

                stmt = con->createStatement();
                res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
                while (res->next()) {
                    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
                    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
                    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
                    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
                    /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column*/
                    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
                }
                delete res;
                delete stmt;
                delete con;

            }
            catch (sql::SQLException& e) {
                cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
                cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line "<< __LINE__ << endl;
                cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
                cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
                cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
            }

            cout << endl;

            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

here is the error log:

Error       'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 243133: truncated mysqlcppconn.dll 8020
Error       bad char for the integer value: '8' (base 8)        lib\mysqlcppconn.dll    428
Error       can't assign to binary operator     \mysqlcppconn.dll   7306

and a millon copy of those and some more...
(i also tried steps found here to no avail: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html#connector-cpp-apps-windows-linking)
P.S., before writing this i was simply getting the "cant read from a corrupt file 0x06" error but for some reason while i was trying to get a copy of the error log for this question i started getting these error above.

Please help! Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so basicly i solved it with the most "programmer" way ever, I just went crazy and deleted the whole project and started again, this time making sure that everything is x64 bit (i made sure that its 64 bits before but it seems i overlooked something) and made sure that i followed the docs word by word, and what do you know, it worked!